# Use calendar.module in my custom module

Tags: datetime

I am creating a module with 2 tabs, a short term calendar and a long term calendar.
I made the tabs, but I'm already stuck..

How can I implement calendar.module to show a calendar on each tab?

This is the code of my tab:

```
  $items['planning/longterm'] = array(
    'title' => 'Long Term',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'planning_page_longterm',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10,
  );
```

In my callback function I try to call the calendar.module via this piece of code:

```
  if (module_exists('calendar')) {
    print theme('calendar_date_default_argument_alter', array('#item' => array('year' => '2013')));
  }
```

Comment: Could you please provide more in formation about what you have already tried. As a question, this is a little short of detail, and it is difficult to see just where to start with an answer.

Comment: I adjusted my post ;)

Comment: why not use views to render the calendar view

Comment: So in my own module I have to use views to generate a calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I would second the comment on trying out Views. You should be able to achieve what you want with the menu tabs and a specific calendar on that page with Views. Maybe try checking out the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1455554). Without more detail in your question it is hard to say, but I'm pretty sure you don't need to make a custom module to do what you have written so far.

Also you probably should also specify which version of Drupal you are using. I'm assuming 7 but it is always better to let people know.

Comment: The thing is that I have to make a custom module, that is the assignment. The module is know still very basic but the functionality's should be more in the future. I'm using drupal 7 indeed. So the problem is to call views or calendar in my own module so that it displays a calendar.

Comment: Is there an error or something that is stopping that theme call from working?

Comment: No, before that call I print a text, the text appears but the calendar not.